# jQuery/modal dialog : how to hide select element when window is showed?

Tags: jquery, hide, modal-dialog

I am trying to hide the "FilterBatch" select input element but nothing happens. The select html input still shows up after the window is open. I also tried to call Hide() from the click event. 
This is the sample code:

```
 var modalRerunConfirmDialog = $("<div id=\"modalRerunConfirmDialog\"/>").dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    title: "UDS Dashboard - Rerun jobs",
    resizable: false,
    draggable: false,
    dialogClass: "dialogOverride",
    buttons: {
        Yes: function () {
            $("#modalRerunConfirmDialog").dialog("close");
            //do something
        },
        No: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    },
    width: 550
});
var msg = Array();
msg[msg.length] = "<br><br><div style=\"font-size:2.0em\">Filter Your Selection</div>";
msg[msg.length] = "<br/><div><select id=\"FilterBatch\" style=\"width:500px;\"></select></div>";
modalRerunConfirmDialog.html(msg.join(" "));

//Bind the Select Box to the Multiselect jQuery plugin
$("#FilterBatch").multiselect({
    noneSelectedText: "Select Batch",
    selectedList: 1,
    multiple: false,
    click: function (event, ui) {
        FilterBatch_Change(ui.value); <= == I also tried to call.Hide() here !! !
    }
});

//populate the first dropdown box inside the modal window
$.each(arrayIDs, function (index, value) {

    $('#FilterBatch').append($('<option>', {
        value: value,
        text: value
    }));
});
$('#FilterBatch').multiselect("refresh");

//hide the select html element <=== this is not working !!!
$("#FilterBatch").hide();

modalRerunConfirmDialog.dialog("open");
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `open` event to your dialog:

```
$("#modalRerunConfirmDialog").on("dialogopen", function() {
    $("#FilterBatch").hide();
});
```

OR you could optimize your code a little, like this:

```
var msg = "<br><br><div style=\"font-size:2.0em\">Filter Your Selection</div> " +
            "<br/><div><select id=\"FilterBatch\" style=\"width:500px;\"></select></div>"; 

 var modalRerunConfirmDialog = $("<div>", {
    id: "modalRerunConfirmDialog",
    html: msg
}).dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    title: "UDS Dashboard - Rerun jobs",
    resizable: false,
    draggable: false,
    dialogClass: "dialogOverride",
    buttons: {
        Yes: function () {
            $("#modalRerunConfirmDialog").dialog("close");
            //do something
        },
        No: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    },
    width: 550,
    open: function(){
        $("#FilterBatch").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: That did not work for me :-( I see the alert popping but cannot hied any element inside the modal window:

        $("#modalRerunConfirmDialog").on("dialogopen", function () {
            alert("open!");
            $("#FilterStatus").hide();
        });
        //open dialog window
        modalRerunConfirmDialog.dialog("open");

Answer (score 0):

The most cool way to do it is using *Knockout.js*

http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=webmail

but you can do it with jQuery!!!

**JS**

```
$("#idToShowOrHide").addClass('hide-me');
```

or

```
$("#idToShowOrHide").removeClass('hide-me');
```

**CSS:**

```
.hide-me{ display:none;}

.iAmOnTop
 { 
    z-index:9999;
    position:fixed;
    margin-left:50%
    margin-top:30%
 }
```